# How to open a pickled file in both read and write simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

How to open a pickled file in both read and write simultaneously in python?
Is there any way to do this or is it imposible.

Comment: A question would be why would you want to?

Comment: so that I would'nt need to change the code when I want to read the file.

Comment: Since you dont post your code its hard to give any real advice but something doesnt smell right about your approach. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: Dude my code is still incomplete thats why I didnt post it. I know it doesn't smell right lol. I'm using an unconventional approach thats the reason it doesn't smell right.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

To do this, open 2 file pointers, one for reading, and another for writing.
For the writing pointer, name it 'file.tmp' or something. After writing to this file, you can replace the other file with the new `file.tmp` file. Psuedocode is:

```
f1 = open('hello.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('hello.txt.tmp', 'w')

f1_contents = f1.read()
# do something with f1_contents
f2.write(f1_contents)

f1.close(); f2.close()

import os
os.rename('hello.txt.tmp', 'hello.txt')
```

Comment: It is possible. I cant say it would be my preferred way to do such a task but it for sure is possible.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, now that i think of it, yeah it is, but its a hassle having to maintain file pointer / buffer state. give me memories of my c++ days in college

Comment: Yeah i posted an answer but again urged the OP to post the real problem as chances are there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: nice code. if it were up to me, id use the file swapping and be done with. less hassle

Comment: oh i totally agree. I would much rather have a file handle for reading and close it once i loaded my pickled object then later open a file handle for writing back to the same file. Something defo doesnt smell right about the problem and i am sure if we seen the OP code or actual problem we would give a much better approach

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt endorse using such code, instead i would urge you to update the question with your actual problem that your trying to solve rather than if its possible to open a pickle object in read and write mode. The reason for wrapping it in the try and except is for the first run when the pickle file doesnt exist so we will create it.

```py
import pickle

try:
    with open("my_pickle.file", "rb+") as pickle_file:
        mylist = pickle.load(pickle_file)
        mylist = [i * 2 for i in mylist]
        pickle_file.seek(0)
        pickle.dump(mylist, pickle_file)
        print(mylist)
except FileNotFoundError as fnfe:
    with open("my_pickle.file", "wb") as pickle_file:
        pickle.dump([1, 2, 3], pickle_file)
```

running this script 5 times, the first time it will create the pickled object the next 4 times it will double the values in the list

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 6]
[4, 8, 12]
[8, 16, 24]
[16, 32, 48]
```

But again this is not something i would recommend. Instead there is probably a better way to approach this problem and get some other answers if you update your question with your actual code and problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should more informatin on what you want to achieve.

It would be tricky to correctly read from a pickle file with more than one object  - you'd have to keep a side structure with the indexes on the start and end of objects.

All in all, it is easier to use sqlite3, create a database file with it, with a single table (name it "pickles") that may contain just two columns: one id for your pickled objects, and the serialized object itself.